# Kendo Grid Rows as Action Links

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this small grid that I would like to have the rows as Action Links.
This is my View

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ThunderBird.Models.WhatIsNewLink>()
                             .Name("grid1")

                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {

                            columns.Bound(c => c.MakeUp).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Content("\\#= MakeUp \\#") + "' target='MakeUp'>Check Out Link For Latest Updates</a>"); HERE
                            columns.Bound(c => c.Clothing);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.LifeStyle);

                            { }

                        })



                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:500px;width:800px;display:none" })
                            .Scrollable()
                            .Groupable()
                            .Sortable()
                            .Selectable(x => x.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
                            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                            .Refresh(true)
                            .PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 50, 100 })

                            .ButtonCount(5))
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                             .Model(model =>
                             {


                                 model.Field(c => c.MakeUp).Editable(false);
                                 model.Field(c => c.Clothing).Editable(false);
                                 model.Field(c => c.LifeStyle).Editable(false);

                             })
                              // .PageSize(new int[] { 10,50,100})
                              .Read(read => read.Action("GetLinks", "WhatIsNew"))

                                                        )
)
```

Here is my Controller

```
public JsonResult GetLinks([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var db = new DataBaseContext();
            var data = db.WhatIsNewLink.Select(x => new { x.MakeUp, x.LifeStyle,x.Clothing }).ToList();
            DataSourceResult rs = data.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(rs);
        }
```

What happens is that when I click the link, opens a new tab with the Grid View again.
What I want is that the ActionLink hold the value from the DB. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you had a look through this article about [actionlink columns](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-mvc-grid-actionlink-column)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this with the help of @Sandman's link. Thanks!

```
columns.Template(@<text>@Html.ActionLink(@item.MakeUp.ToString(), "GetLinks", "WhatIsNew") </text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='#=MakeUp#</a>").Title("MakeUp");
                        columns.Bound(c => c.MakeUp).Hidden();...
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is: The link is wrong. Does the target 'MakeUp' exist?

Try removing the target attribute or use '_blank'.